# Rewrite Rmarkdown tags

Tags: r, r-markdown, rpres

I'm curious if it is easily possible to add or modify any tags in Rmarkdown. For example, I seldom use ~~ for overstrike, but would love instead to attach that to, say, the incremental class when making presentations.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you can change via Rmarkdown. All of the parsing seems to be handled by `pandoc` which is a separate program that does the actual parsing. In theory you could write your own "pandoc writer" that can change how that tag is rendered in a particular file format but that will need to be coded in Haskell or lua.

Comment: @MrFlick is correct.

Comment: I ask as I swear (and I might be hallucinating) I remember an old answer on the rstudio support site, which I can of course no longer fine, where a dev advised someone to do something to change the meaning of ~~, and it seemed straightforward. Kicking myself for not bookmarking it!